# EF 6 Code-First not creating one table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm a little stuck with EF Code-first to create a new database. We have an existing database and used the Model-First approach successfully. Now I would like to existing model to create a new database at run-time like this:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MDREntities>
{    
    public void InitializeDatabase(MDREntities dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext.Database.Exists())
        {
            // Delete the existing database
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "ALTER DATABASE [" + dbContext.Database.Connection.Database + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
            dbContext.Database.Delete();
        }
        // Create new database
        dbContext.Database.Create();

        // Add initial data
        addMasterData(dbContext);

        // Commit changes.
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The above runs through successfully and **all my tables are created except for 1**.

I've done the following without any luck:

- The table does exists in the edmx model.
- The model .tt file does generate the class for the table.
- The context .tt file does generate a DbSet for the table.
- I've removed my edmx model and recreated from the database.

Is it possible to "trace" what `dbContext.Database.Create();` does and if something did in fact go wrong?

I also noticed that the "missing" table is the only one with a **composite PK**, could this be a problem?

**Update:**

When I had a look at `SQL Profiler`, I found this comment saying that the table is ignored. Unfortunately it doesn't say why:

```
-- Ignoring entity set with defining query: [MDRModelStoreContainer].[tblRelatedPatient]
```

Here's the table mapped in the edmx:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `dbContext.Database.Log = System.Console.Write` to get the SQL output dumped to the console.

Comment: @JasonGerard, unfortunately `dbContext.Database.Log` didn't log `CREATE TABLE` statements, only `ALTER DATABASE...` and `INSERT INTO...`. I did have a look at profiler. Updating question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The original table did not have a Primary Key**.

Even though the edmx showed a `Composite Primary Key` in the designer, the table did not get created successfully from the edmx Model until I actually updated the original database and refreshed the edmx, strange...

- Add a PK to underlying table (original mapped to edmx)
- Refresh edmx model
- Now `dbContext.Database.Create();` creates the table succesfully.